# How to get user input to look in string

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a paragraph and then have a search bar to look up if there is a given word in the parapragh. If I write "are" in the search bar, it should tell me through alert "The word is in the text." And if I write something that is not in the text, it should tell me "No, it's not there.".

Could look something like:

```
<p id="p1"> Hi, how are you?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Search</button>

<script>
function getInputValue() {
  let text = document.getElementById("p1");
  let textElement = document.getElementById(myInput).value;

  if (text.indexOf("textElement") >-1){
    return true;
  } else if {
    (text.indexOf("textElement") =-1)
    return false;
  }

  console.log(myInput);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `unction getInputValue(){` I assume that is copy paste error

Comment: `if (text.indexOf("textElement") >-1){` will search for the literal value "textElement". To search for the variable, remove the quotes: `if (text.indexOf(textElement) >-1){`

Comment: you return so i is not going to get to the console.log line. So instead of returning, shouldn't you be using alert? You `myInput` is not defined and you are looking for the string 'textElement' not the variable. You have a lot of small typos

Comment: Also, `let text = document.getElementById("p1");` returns the element, not its text value.

Comment: `text.indexOf("textElement") =-1` is **assigning** `-1`, not **comparing**. You cannot assign a value to a number.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question very carefully and I think following is your answer:

```js
function getInputValue() {
      let text = document.getElementById("p1").textContent;
      let textElement = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

        if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(textElement.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            alert("The word is in the text.");
        } else {
            alert("No, it's not there.");  
        }
      }
```

```html
    <p id="p1"> Hi, how are you?</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
      <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Search</button>
```

Comment: If you knew how long I have been trying to get this result... THANK YOU SO MUCH!:)

Comment: Madefaar Abbas, is it possible to do so that it returns "The word is in the text." if you where searching for "hi" with lowercase letter. So it will accept the word no matter if it's lowercase or uppercase letters?

Comment: @Sebastian I have fixed all of your above improvements in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The approach was already quite good. Enclosed is your revised Javascript. It is case insensitive.

```js
function getInputValue() {
  
  let text = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
  
  let textElement = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  
  if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(textElement.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
    alert("word found.");
  } else if (text.indexOf(textElement.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
    alert("nothing founded");  
  }
  
  console.log(myInput);
}
```

```html
<p id="p1"> Hi, how are you?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue()">Search</button>
```